# Conditional Jump (jg) after comparison (cmp)

Tags: assembly

Here is a snippet of code that my book provided. The question asks whether the execution 
bx,1 or ax,10 will be executed. Looking at the code I want to say Ax,10 will be executed, an answer online says bx,1 will be executed, and my emulator says both are executed. Will someone help me understand what is really going on here?

```
mov cx,5
not cx
mov dx,10
cmp cx,dx
jg jump1
mov bx,1
jump1:
mov ax,10
```

Comment: What was your reasoning?

Comment: Well not cx, gives cx the value FFFAh which is greater than 000Ah so i thought the conditional jump was satisfied.

Comment: Fair enough. That would have happened if it was `ja` (jump if above) instead of `jg`. It can be tricky to remember which one is which.

Comment: Read up on the way issues of sign and negative numbers are treated in the CPU. FFFA is the same as -6, and JG treats it as the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's trace. Before the CMP line the value of CX is -6 (the result of NOT on 5). The JG command performs a signed comparison - it doesn't treat negative numbers as large positive ones (JA and JB do).

So CX (-6) is not greater than DX (10), and the conditional jump is not taken. So both lines execute.

Comment: Thanks! I see what is happening now.